# Example of a nonempty subset U of R 2 such that U is closed under addition and under taking additive inverses but U is not a subspace of R 2 .

Tags: linear-algebra

The question from a Stanford assignment requests:

Example of a nonempty subset U of  $R^2$  such that U is closed under addition and under
taking additive inverses but U is not a subspace of $R^2$.

The answer says:

Proof. Consider the subset $Z^2$. It is closed under addition; however, it is not closed under scalar multiplication. For example $\sqrt2$ (1, 1) = ($\sqrt2$, $\sqrt2$) ∈/ $Z^2$.

However, doesn't the scalar multiple need to be a member of the subset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No! The scalar multiple is from the field over which the vector space is defined. In this case you have a real vector space so the scalar can be any real number.

Comment: The Q is badly formed.  It does not specify the field $F$ for which $(\Bbb R^2,F) $ is   the vector-space under consideration. However we must have $F\supset \Bbb Q$ so the set $\Bbb Z^2,$ as in the A by Jose Carlos Santos, is an example.

Answer (score 0):

No. The set $\mathbb{Z}^2$ is just the set of all ordered pairs of integers. That's all. And, yes, it is not closed for multiplication by arbitrary real scalars.